# Which sentence below is correct?

Tags: grammar

1. The intentions change when the phone will ring.
2. The intentions will change when the phone will ring.

and why?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say definitively without more information about the meaning you want to convey/the context, but I would say neither is correct.

Instead, I'd suggest:

[His/her] intentions will change when the phone rings.

or

[His/her] intentions change when the phone rings.

First things first: "will" can be used as an auxiliary (or helper) verb, used in conjunction with other verbs. Often "will [+ some other verb]" is used to express futurity, as English doesn't have a future tense.

Now, addressing the first part (or clause) of your sentence, "The intentions [will] change," depending on what you want to express, it may be correct to use "will change." You might use "will change" if you're trying to emphasize the change of state (original intentions to different intentions) and that it happens in the future as a result of another future event (the phone ringing). On the other hand, if you get rid of the helper verb, you're locating the change of intentions as well as the ringing of the phone in the present.

Regarding the second clause of your sentence, While "will" sometimes can be used in a conditional clause, I don't think your case is one of the exceptions to that general rule about auxiliary verbs in conditional clauses. By itself, "when the phone rings" is enough to indicate an event taking place in the future; it could also mean the event is taking place in the present. How you choose to write the first clause (future or present tense) determines whether this second one refers to the future or present.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. The intentions change when the phone will ring.

"The intentions change" - the simple tense.

It means they change *again and again*, every time when the phone rings (so NO when the phone WILL ring - it is grammatically incorrect).

> 2. The intentions will change when the phone will ring.

Correct.